# Рубрикация текста

Tags: общие-вопросы

Надо составить рубрикацию текста. Я все сделала, просто прошу просмотреть и, если кто-нибудь понимает, указать на ошибку. Может, я что-то сделала не так?

***P.S. Прежде чем закрывать вопрос, прочитайте внимательно: я не прошу за меня ничего выполнять!***

Задание. Рубрицируйте фрагмент текста Федерального закона «О землеустройстве»
К полномочиям Российской Федерации в области регулирования проведения землеустройства относятся:

> установление порядка проведения землеустройства; координация деятельности федеральных органов исполнительной власти, органов исполнительной власти субъектов Российской Федерации, органов местного самоуправления при проведении землеустройства;
>
> проведение землеустройства на землях, находящихся в федеральной собственности;
>
> принятие нормативных правовых актов о землеустройстве; установление
> порядка государственной экспертизы землеустроительной документации; >организация и осуществление федерального государственного надзора в области землеустройства; разработка, согласование и реализация генеральной схемы землеустройства территории Российской Федерации;
>
> управление государственным фондом данных, полученных в результате проведения землеустройства;
>
> другие установленные федеральными законами полномочия Российской Федерации в области регулирования проведения землеустройства.

Составила рубрику.

Глава1  Федеральный закон  «О землеустройстве»

ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЕ РЕГУЛИРОВАНИЕ ПРОВЕДЕНИЯ ЗЕМЛЕУСТРОЙСТВА

§1.Полномочия Российской Федерации в области регулирования проведения землеустройства

1.1.1 Организация и порядок проведения землеустройства

1.1.2 Правовое регулирование отношений при проведении землеустройства

1.1.3 Основания проведения землеустройства

1.1.4 Передача осуществления полномочий федеральных органов исполнительной власти в области регулирования проведения землеустройства органам исполнительной власти субъектов Российской Федерации (введена Федеральным законом от 13.07.2015 №233-ФЗ)

1.1.5 Государственная экспертиза землеустроительной документации

1.1.6 Федеральный государственный надзор в области землеустройства (в ред. Федерального закона от 18.07.2011 №242-ФЗ)

1.1.7 Технические условия и требования проведения землеустройства

1.1.8 Государственный фонд данных, полученных в результате проведения землеустройства

1.1.9 Государственное регулирование проведения землеустройства

Comment: Отсутствует ряд пробелов: после точки всегда идёт пробел, между словом и цифрой — тоже. Нет причин не ставить точки на концах строк в перечислении.

Comment: @shampar, спасибо, это все понятно. Меня больше всего интересовала организация рубрики. Насколько она корректна.

Comment: Если «это всё понятно», то будет правильно напомнить, что ресурс занимается исключительно проблемой под названием Русский язык. Форматирование и редактирование технических, юридических и пр. спец. текстов — не проблема языка.

Comment: Наталья, считаю нужным уточнить, что ваш вопрос нельзя отнести к запрещенным на нашем сайте. Надеюсь, вам будет дан полезный ответ!

Comment: @Aer, спасибо.Надеюсь, кто-н ответит.

Comment: shampar, рубрикация имет дело с текстом. Составлять перечени тоже зависит от уровня владения языка. Поэтому, думаю, вопрос будет интересен и для других.